# Rails 4 - Display choices as radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, simple-form-for

I am working on a Rails 4 application, using simple_form for input. There are several model fields that can take well-known answers or a free-form answer. For example, for a field `fruit:string` I would like to display `"Apple"`, `"Banana"`, `"Other"`. If the user chooses `"Other"`, they can enter any free-form text. Currently, all I can do is use `<%= f.input :fruit %>` and a blank textbox shows up. Is it possible to show radio buttons instead? I can do

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :fruit, [["Apple", "Apple"], ["Banana", "Banana"]], :first, :last %>
```

but that does not provide the "Other" option. The goal is to record "Apple", "Banana" or the specified (typed-in) value if "Other" was chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Form lets you us `as: :radio_buttons` on a collection, like so

```
<%= f.input :fruit, collection: ['apple', 'banana', 'other'], as: :radio_buttons %>
```

See the [collection section of the SimpleForm README](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections) for more information on collection inputs.

Comment: My question was about how I could let a user enter data for "other" option, not just present the three options. Please re-read my question.

Comment: Simply put, you'll likely use jquery to display a text box in that case.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to have the f.collection_radio_buttons followed by the f.input, both with the same name.  Then, selectively enable the f.input based on the selected radio button with jquery or javascript.  For this to work, you would probably also want to add an ['Other']['Other'] option.

EDIT
Maybe something along these lines:

```
f.collection_radio_buttons :fruit, [['Apple','Apple'],['Orange','Orange'],['Other','Other']], :first, :last
f.text_field :fruit


$("input:radio[name='foo[fruit]']").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == 'Other'){
    $("input:text[name='foo[fruit]']").show().prop( "disabled", false);
  }else{
    $("input:text[name='foo[fruit]']").hide().prop( "disabled", true );
  }});
```

Because they have the same name, Rails will use the last value (the text field in this case if it is enabled), otherwise it will use the selected radio button.

Comment: That is the question - how would something like that work with Rails 4? Is there an example you could provide?

Comment: Rails 4 would just use the last value sent with that name.  Updated the answer with an example using jQuery.